# Read a Static Json File and View it as table in ASP .Net Core

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I am trying to read a .json File and return the value as a table in asp .net Core 3.1!
I am new at working with asp .net core, so please help me from a beginners perspective.

Consider the code snippet below. My problem is that I cannot pass the values from the controller to the view.

I encounter this exception:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type '.Sample.Models.Mstype', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'Sample.Models.Mstypes'.
```

**Controller**

```
  public IActionResult Run()
        {
            ...

            var webClient = new WebClient();
            var json = webClient.DownloadString(@"/app/results/type.json");
            var mstypes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Mstype>(json);
            
            return View(mstypes);

        }
```

**Mstype.cs**

```
  public int CIS { get; set; }
        public int PPMS { get; set; }
        public int RRMS { get; set; }
        public int SPMS { get; set; }
        public int not_sure { get; set; }
```

**Mstypes.cs**

```
 public class Mstypes
    {
        public IList<Mstype> mstypes { get; set; }
    }
```

**View**

```
@model Fed_PiP.Models.Mstypes

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Run";
}


<table class="table">

    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(Model => Model.mstypes[0].CIS)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(Model => Model.mstypes[0].PPMS)

            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(Model => Model.mstypes[0].RRMS)

            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(Model => Model.mstypes[0].SPMS)

            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(Model => Model.mstypes[0].not_sure)

            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

       
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Model.mstypes.FirstOrDefault().CIS
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Model.mstypes.FirstOrDefault().PPMS
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Model.mstypes.FirstOrDefault().RRMS
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Model.mstypes.FirstOrDefault().SPMS
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Model.mstypes.FirstOrDefault().not_sure
                </td>
            </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

and finally
json file

```
{"CIS":11,"PPMS":12,"RRMS":6,"SPMS":11,"not_sure":10}
```

also, I have a question
is there any way to make a dynamic table from the static JSON files?
I mean without defining the model or ViewModel just reading and returning the values from the static file to the tables?

Comment: What's the model type declared in the view? I think you should do `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Mstypes>(json)`

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya I updated the snip also, Mstypes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very clear from the error message, the view accept a `Mstypes` type model, while you pass a `Mstype` to it.

So, you can encapsulate `mstypes` convert it to `Mstypes` type in your controller.

```
public IActionResult Run()
{
    var json = "{ 'CIS':11,'PPMS':12,'RRMS':6,'SPMS':11,'not_sure':10}";
    var mstype1 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Mstype>(json);
    Mstypes mstypes = new Mstypes
    {
        mstypes = new List<Mstype> { mstype1 }
    };

    return View(mstypes);
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Great, Works!
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

What if you change:

`var mstypes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Mstype>(json);`

to

`var mstypes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Mstypes>(json);`

Your .json file should be something like:

```
{
  mstypes : [
    {"CIS":11,"PPMS":12,"RRMS":6,"SPMS":11,"not_sure":10},
    {"CIS":11,"PPMS":12,"RRMS":6,"SPMS":11,"not_sure":10},
    {"CIS":11,"PPMS":12,"RRMS":6,"SPMS":11,"not_sure":10},
    {"CIS":11,"PPMS":12,"RRMS":6,"SPMS":11,"not_sure":10},
    {"CIS":11,"PPMS":12,"RRMS":6,"SPMS":11,"not_sure":10},
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thank you!
But it returned Null Value!
<ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'source')
>

Comment: Your json file do not reflect the schema you want, and use in your View

Comment: what it should be?

Comment: To match the json above, the type should be `Mstype[]` for both the `@Model` line and the call to `DeserializeObject`